# AlarmRepeat function in Arduino

Tags: time, arduino, repeat, alarm

I am using the Time.h and TimeAlarms.h libraries in Arduino. I try to call a function on specific times of the day (every day). The function is called on the first day, but then on the next day it seems like the alarm ceases to work, although it should repeat every day. Any ideas what's wrong with my sketch?

```
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>

#define TIME_MSG_LEN  11   // time sync to PC is HEADER followed by Unix time_t as ten ASCII digits
#define TIME_HEADER  'T'   // Header tag for serial time sync message
#define TIME_REQUEST  7    // ASCII bell character requests a time sync message 

// The constant variables used in the code:
const unsigned long shock_delay = 10;       // shock stimulus duration (s)

// Edit below only if you make changes to the hardware configuration:
const int tonePin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin
const int shockPin = 12;      // the number of the shocker pin
const int buzzerOut = 8;      // the number of the tone producer
const int trialButton=2;      // the number of the trial button
const int controlButton=3;    // the number of the control button

// Define the variables that will change in the code
unsigned int Interval1;                // the interval between the beginning of the hour and the first footshock
unsigned int Interval2;                // the interval between the first and the second footshock 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);               // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps  
  setTime(23,59,50,10,4,15);          // The current time (HH,MM,SS,DD,MM,YY)

  // Define the position of the different digital pins
  pinMode(tonePin, OUTPUT);         // The tone LED (red)
  pinMode(shockPin, OUTPUT);        // The shock output, which will coincide with green LED
  pinMode(trialButton, INPUT);      // The trial input button
  pinMode(controlButton, INPUT);    // The control input button

   Alarm.alarmRepeat(20,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function          
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(21,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(23,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(0,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(1,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(2,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(3,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(4,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(5,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(6,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
   Alarm.alarmRepeat(7,00,0,RandomShock);        // Initiate the user defined RandomShock function
  }

void  loop(){  
    // Create a message that gives the current time and date on the monitor     
    if(Serial.available() ) 
      {
        processSyncMessage();
      }
      if(timeStatus() == timeNotSet) 
        Serial.println("waiting for sync message");
      else     
          digitalClockDisplay();                                       // The function that calls on the time display
          Alarm.delay(1000);                                           // Delay of 1 minute between time display
           }

     void digitalClockDisplay(){
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  printDigits(second());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(day());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(month());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(year()); 
  Serial.println(); 
}

void printDigits(int digits){
  // utility function for digital clock display: prints preceding colon and leading 0
  Serial.print(":");
  if(digits < 10)
    Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}

void processSyncMessage() {
  // if time sync available from serial port, update time and return true
  while(Serial.available() >=  TIME_MSG_LEN ){  // time message consists of header & 10 ASCII digits
    char c = Serial.read() ; 
    Serial.print(c);  
    if( c == TIME_HEADER ) {       
      time_t pctime = 0;
      for(int i=0; i < TIME_MSG_LEN -1; i++){   
        c = Serial.read();          
        if( c >= '0' && c <= '9'){   
          pctime = (10 * pctime) + (c - '0') ; // convert digits to a number    
        }
      }   
      setTime(pctime);   // Sync Arduino clock to the time received on the serial port
    }  
  }
}

void RandomShock () {
       Interval1 = random(0,60);                               // Random value between 0 and 59 [min]
       digitalWrite(tonePin,HIGH);                             // Indicate the shock program is ON by the red LED
       Alarm.delay(Interval1*60000);                           // Wait for the duration of the first interval
       digitalWrite(tonePin,LOW);                              // Turn the red LED OFF
       digitalWrite(shockPin, HIGH);                           // Apply the first shock (green LED will turn ON)
       Serial.println("Applying an electeric shock at:");      // Write a message indicating a shock is applied
       digitalClockDisplay();                                  // Display the time during which the shock was applied
       Alarm.delay(shock_delay*1000);                          // The duration of the shock [10 seconds]
       digitalWrite(shockPin, LOW);                            // Terminate the first shock (green LED will turn OFF)
       Interval2 = random(0,(61-Interval1));                   // Randomly asign a value to the second interval [min]
       digitalWrite(tonePin,HIGH);                             // Indicate the shock program is ON by the red LED
       Alarm.delay(Interval2*60000-20000);                     // Wait for the duration of the second interval
       digitalWrite(tonePin,LOW);                              // Turn the red LED OFF
       digitalWrite(shockPin,HIGH);                            // Apply the second shock (green LED will turn ON)
       Serial.println("Applying an electeric shock at:");      // Write a message indicating a shock is applied
       digitalClockDisplay();                                  // Display the time during which the shock was applied
       Alarm.delay(shock_delay*1000);                          // The duration of the shock [10 seconds]
       digitalWrite(shockPin,LOW);                             // Terminate the second shock
       digitalWrite(tonePin,HIGH);                             // Indicate the shock program is ON by the red LED
       Alarm.delay((60-Interval1-Interval2)*60000);            // Wait until the hour is completed
       digitalWrite(tonePin,LOW);                              // Turn the red LED OFF
}
```

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are no error messages. The sketch is running smoothly. I ran a test trial and noticed that it worked fine on the first day, but once the date switched on midnight the alarmRepeat function ceased to call my function (RandomShock). As I understand it, it shouldn't be this way. AlarmRepeat should call my function every day on the same time.

Comment: SOLVED: There are two problems with the sketch that I wrote:
1) Alarm.alarmRepeat function does not seem to be able to call my function exactly at midnight (00:00:00), however, if I schedule it to any other time (e.g., 00:00:01) it works just fine.
2) There is a limit to the number of alarms you can schedule: the maximum number of alarms is 6. The solution is either to change this threshold, or to reduce the number of alarms. 
After correcting for these two issues, the sketch work smoothly.

Comment: @cassiopeiam please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted (you won't gain any rep for that but I'll upvote it).

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than 6 alarms just look for that at TimeAlarms.h on the library:

```
#if defined(__AVR__)
#define dtNBR_ALARMS 6 // max is 255
#else
#define dtNBR_ALARMS 12  // assume non-AVR has more memory
#endif
```

and change it to your need (example:24)

```
#if defined(__AVR__)
#define dtNBR_ALARMS 24 // max is 255
#else
#define dtNBR_ALARMS 12  // assume non-AVR has more memory
#endif
```

Comment: this should be set outside, modify lib is not good idea. but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the sketch that I wrote:

1. Alarm.alarmRepeat function does not seem to be able to call my
   function exactly at midnight (00:00:00), however, if I schedule it
   to any other time (e.g., 00:00:01) it works just fine.
2. There is a limit to the number of alarms you can schedule: the
   maximum number of alarms is 6. The solution is either to change this threshold, or to reduce the number of alarms.

After correcting for these two issues the sketch work smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that TimeAlarm library is unable to set an alarm to midnight 
https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimeAlarms/issues/3

Try this pull request https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimeAlarms/pull/4